# Route Id Not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I am creating a project called doctor management system. I am now  stuck in this that when a user logged in his page my route function get the specific id & then show his information. But when I logged in it did not get id & that's  why it put some error but When I manuaaly enter the id it worked perfectly ok. I did not find why this occurs. Please Guys Help Me.

My Route File

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'auth'
    ], function() {


        Route::get('/home/{profile_id}', [
        'as' => 'admin',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
    ]);

        Route::get('/profile/{profile_id}', array('as' =>'profile' ,'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'));
```

My profile Controler is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index($profile_id)
    {
        $profile = User::find($profile_id);
        // if(!$profile) {
        //     return redirect()->route('logout')->with(['fail' => 'Profile Not Found']);
        // }
        return view('admin.article.index',['profile' => $profile]);
    }
```

The error is
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what URL is being accessed, so I suppose it is *whatever_your_domain_is/profile/{id}*.

The error being presented is telling you there is no route for the URL being entered.

I suppose you wanna show the profile for logged-in user, so actually you don't need any {id} in route, you can:

```
$profile = Auth::user();
return view('admin.article.index', compact('profile'));
```

But if you do want to show other user's profile, just check out your URL.

**Some things I've noticed:**

Your 'profile/{profile_id}' route is outside of Route group, that's the way it is supposed to be?

Choose a single pattern to write your code. You've written array using to different notations: **array()** and **[]**. Read about Coding Stardards (e.g. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md).

Comment: How do i update any information in my profile file using this notation?

Comment: Do you mean array notation? array() and [] works the same way.

Comment: I got it. you can change any property using something like `$profile->name = 'My new name';`, then `$profile->save();`. That's it.

Comment: tnx again For Your Help.